# error in debugging the algorithm

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make an algorithm in Matlab that scans the character array from left to right and if it encounters a space, it should do nothing, but if it encounters 2 consecutive spaces, it should start printing the remaining quantities of array from next line. for example,

```
inpuut='a bc  d';
```

after applying this algorithm, the final output should have to be:

```
a bc

d
```

but this algorithm is giving me the output as:

```
a bc

d d
```

Also, if someone has got a more simpler algorithm to do this task, do help me please :)

```
m=1; t=1;
inpuut='a bc  d';

while(m<=(length(inpuut)))

    if((inpuut(m)==' ')&&(inpuut(m+1)==' '))
        n=m;
        fprintf(inpuut(t:(n-1)));
        fprintf('\n');
        t=m+2;
    end    

    fprintf(inpuut(t));

    if(t<length(inpuut))
        t=t+1;
    elseif(t==length(inpuut))
        t=t-1;
    else
    end

    m=m+1;

end
fprintf('\n');
```

Comment: @Yvon, i've an array containing text, i want to scan it from left to right just as strtok command of matlab, and display the characters; but i want that if it encounters 2 consecutive spaces while scanning from left to right, it should start printing the remaining characters from next line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I gave up telling why your code doesn't work. This is a working one.

```
inpuut='a bc  d  ';

% remove trailing space
while (inpuut(end)==' ')
    inpuut(end)=[];
end

str = regexp(inpuut, '  ', 'split');
for ii = 1:length(str)
    fprintf('%s\n', str{ii});
end
```

[`regexp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with `'split'` option splits the string into a cell array, with delimiter defined in the matching expression.

[`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) is capable of handling complicated strings, much more than printing a single string.

You can remove the trailing space before printing, *or* do it inside the loop (check if the last cell is empty, but it's more costly).

Comment: in which part of the algorithm, i've to make this change? i also know that my code is failing when it encounters one or more spaces in the end, the problem is that i'm not able to fix it :(
i know these are a bit foolish sort of questions to ask, but as i'm very new to matlab, so i don't have that much idea of it :(

Comment: @Yvon - I laughed out loud when I read your first statement.  That alone gave you a +1.  However, good job in fixing the code :)

Comment: @user3801619 - Replace **all of your code** with the one Yvon has given you.

Comment: thank u so very much @Yvon :)
its working fine now (Y)

Comment: +1 although you could also use `deblank` to get rid of trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`regexprep`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) to replace two consecutive spaces by a line feed:

```
result_string = regexprep(inpuut, '  ', '\n');
```

If you need to remove trailing spaces: use this first:

```
result_string = regexprep(inpuut, '  $', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution without using regex, but I assumed you wanted to print on 2 lines maximum.

Example: with 'a b  c  hello':

```
a b
c  hello
```

and not:

```
a b
c
hello
```

In any case, here is the code:

```
inpuut = 'a b  c';
while(length(inpuut) > 2)
    % Read the next 2 character
    first2char = inpuut(1:2);
    switch(first2char)
        case '  ' % 2 white spaces
            % we add a new line and print the rest of the input
            fprintf('\n%s', inpuut(3:end));
            inpuut = [];
        otherwise % not 2 white spaces
            % Just print one character
            fprintf('%s', inpuut(1))
            inpuut(1) = [];
    end    
end
fprintf('%s\n', inpuut);
```